# vectorized parallel selection that's random?

Tags: r, vectorization, random

I have two vectors "H" and "L" that have 200 numeric values. I want to create a third vector called "HL" that contains 200 random samples from H and L. However, I would like them to be selected in parallel, the same way the pmin and pmax function do.

Simplified example:

```
H <- 1:5
L <- 6:10

# rbind(H,L)
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# H    1    2    3    4    5
# L    6    7    8    9   10
# intended result is then a random pick from each 'column' shown above, e.g:

HL <- c(6,2,8,4,10)
```

Is there a way of doing this without using a loop?

Any advice would be much appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Can you give a specific example of the output you want? eg: if `H` and `L` were say `1:5` and `6:10` and you wanted to get 5 random samples in `HL` what would you get back from this analysis?

Comment: In addition is there sampling with replacement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simpliy need N samples from a bernouli (ie, 0 or 1) distribution, where `N` is the number of values in H/L. You then use the sampling to pick from H or L respectively.  using `ifelse` ensures the "parallel selection" you require.

```
set.seed(1)
N <- length(H)
HorL <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)

# the select
results <- ifelse(HorL, H, L)

results
# [1]  6  7  3  4 10
```

### This all wraps up as a nice one liner:

```
ifelse( rbinom(H, 1, 0.5), H, L)
```

---

from @Arun: 
A (relatively) faster way of implementing this (removing the need for `ifelse`) would be:

```
idx <- which(!as.logical(rbinom(H, 1, 0.5)))
vv <- H
vv[idx] <- L[idx]
```

---

### EXPLANATION

@Gabriel, The idea is that you are selecting from one of two options. You can effectively flip a coin and, if heads, select from H, if tails, select from L.  This is a Bernouli Distribution, a more general form is the Binomial distribution.  R has a facility to offer random numbers of just such a fashion.

Thus we ask R for `N` many of these, then select from H or L accordingly.

The "select from .. " part is the `R` trickery.

- Notice that we can think of `0, 1` as `TRUE, FALSE` or `A, B`, etc.
- Using the `ifelse` approach should be somewhat self explanatory. If it is TRUE, select from one source, if it is FALSE, select from the other.

Arun's approach is more creative. His approach uses the same "flip a coin" mechanism for choosing between sets, but has the benefit of speed. (We are speaking nanoseconds, but still). 
His approach essentially says:

- Start with one group, say H.
- Flip a coin.
- Whenever the coin is Tails, replace that element of H with the same indexed element of L. 
  *(Notice that the "same index" aspect is what you are refering to as "parallel selection")*

Comment: @Arun - very nice improvement!  about half the time!

Comment: @Arun Thanks for your help.  
I'm new to the site and 'r'. I'm actually overwhelmed by the support here.  
I have used Arun's code but am still working on understanding it. Nonetheless the final output is what I wanted :)

Comment: Ahh that clears a lot up for me thank you.     

I was a little confused to its randomness due to the output always being the same numbers. But I realised that my 'set.seed' was causing the object to contain the same integers.

Answer (score -1):

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1350)

# Create an example data table:
dt <- data.table(ID=1:200,H=sample(1:1000,200),L=sample(1001:2000,200),key="ID")
# (If you already have a data frame 'df', you can use):
# dt <- as.data.table(df)

set.seed(5655)
# Add a column that randomly samples between H and L:
dt[,HL:=sample(c(H,L),1),by=ID]
dt

#       ID   H    L   HL
#  1:   1 837 1391 1391
#  2:   2 999 1573 1573
#  3:   3 566 1275  566
#  4:   4 347 1709 1709
#  5:   5 129 1627  129
# ---                  
#196: 196  67 1879 1879
#197: 197 652 1811 1811
#198: 198 569 1160 1160
#199: 199  17 1026   17
#200: 200 221 1500 1500
```

Edit 2:
My initial answer would give incorrect values if H had duplicates, as pointed in the comments.  I had added timings that showed `data.table` was faster, but when I correct the answer it does turn out to be much slower, as suggested in the comments.  (It was faster with the wrong answer since it was grouping by duplicate values, so it had many fewer rows to consider...)

In short, I was wrong, and you might be better off with the other answer.

---

here is a proper benchmark :

```
set.seed(1350) 

H <- sample(1:200, 200) 
L <- sample(201:400, 200)

usingDataTable <- quote({
  dt <- data.table(H, L)
  dt[,HL:=sample(c(H,L),1),by=H]
})


dt2 <- data.table(H, L)
usingDataTable.NoInitialize <- quote({
  dt2[,HL:=sample(c(H,L),1),by=H]
})

usingVectors <- quote ({
  ifelse( rbinom(H, 1, 0.5), H, L)
})



microbenchmark(eval(usingVectors), eval(usingDataTable), eval(usingDataTable.NoInitialize), times=100L)

Unit: microseconds
                              expr      min       lq   median        uq      max neval
                eval(usingVectors)   55.021   61.148   66.760   69.4605 1682.163   100
              eval(usingDataTable) 1635.676 1745.437 1795.245 1851.0950 3629.179   100
 eval(usingDataTable.NoInitialize) 1458.573 1537.618 1596.237 1669.3750 3683.756   100
```

Comment: While I admire the use of `data.table`, this might actually be a good example of when doing so would be much _**slower**_ than not.   Notice also, that the use of `by` is going to give you troubles when there are duplicated values in `H`.  I would recommend at least using `dt[, HL := ifelse(rbinom(.N, 1, 0.5), H, L)]`

Comment: @Gabriel although it's a solution, Ricardo's is much more efficient. You don't need to sample for each group.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta and @Arun, I think `data.table` is more efficient, not less.  Let me know if I'm missing something... Edit: I just saw your edited comment, @RicardoSaporta, and you're correct about the duplicated values in H.

Comment: @dnlbrky, your solution I think, now, is *wrong*. You've only 2000 unique values and you've generated a million values. So, your subsetting/grouping happens only 2000 times.. (and so is your sampling)... Ex: try this: `dt <- data.table(H=c(1,1,1,2,2), L=1:5)` and check your results.

Comment: data.table is much more efficient relative to `data.frame` and to many aspects of `*ply` style functions.  It's also significantly faster with larger data.    As for the timing, try using `microbenchmark`, as I am getting a 20x~30x decrease from data.table

Comment: Didnt mean to start a whole thing here @dnlbrky, sorry about that :)    My only point was that this was probably one of those times when using `data.table` is probably unhelpful (that is, just for this specific problem) and slower (see the benchmarks).  And keep in mind, I also tend to opt for data.table solutions when possible.